# Weak convergence of order statistics

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I've encountered the following problem:
Let $U_1,...,U_n$ be iid uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and let $U_{n(k_n)}$ denote the $k_n$-th order statistic where $k_n$ is chosen, s.t. $\frac{k_n}{n}=p+\frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}+o\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ where $c$ is some constant and $p\in(0,1)$. Then it should hold (and this is my question): 
$$\left(U_{n(k_n)}-p\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$$
converges weakly to some random variable. Does someone know why this is true and how to identify the limit?
Thanks a lot!